# UIbutton not on the top of tableViewHeader isn't tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I want to make a `tableViewHeader` from `xib`.

In `xib` I have the following `hierarchy of views`

[image]

But this way `ActionButton` isn't tapped, nothing overlays it and `userInteractionEnabled = YES` for it.

The button becomes active only when I put it into `ZeroScreenView`, so the only workaround I found is to place button directly on the `ZeroScreenView`.

Does someone know why does this it happen?

Is there any way to make the button `tappable` when it lays onto `Labels Container`?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what problem you are getting. But through code I have done like this

```
UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,40)];
headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
UIButton *buttn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[buttn setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[buttn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
buttn.titleLabel.font = CUSTOM_FONT_ROMAN(15);
[buttn setFrame:headerView.frame];
[buttn setBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor]];
[buttn addTarget:self action:@selector(tapButton) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[headerView addSubview:buttn];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;
```